# unreachable code on throw statement in angular 6

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am currently upgrading angular 4 to angular 6 code and just updated the catch error and and throw functions. I am getting a syntactical error on throw statement. Its say unreachable code. Could somebody tell me what the problem is

```
  upload(url: string, body: any) {
        this._userService.touched.next(null); // touch
        const stream = this._proxy.fileUpload(url, body).pipe(map(ret => ret.originalResponse) , catchError((error: any) => {
            if (error.status === 401) {
                this._userService.unauthorized();
                return of(null);
            } else {
                return throw(error);
            }
        }));
        return stream;
    }
```

Comment: Can you also add full error that you are getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `throwError` Observable creation function instead of `throw`.

Try this:

```
upload(url: string, body: any) {
        this._userService.touched.next(null); // touch
        const stream = this._proxy.fileUpload(url, body).pipe(map(ret => ret.originalResponse) , catchError((error: any) => {
            if (error.status === 401) {
                this._userService.unauthorized();
                return of(null);
            } else {
                return throwError(error);
            }
        }));
        return stream;
    }
```